# Is there an API for ethereum address monitoring? Or how to get notifications when an address is paided

Tags: ethereum

Consider the simple scenario: some address transfers 100 usdt to address A; is there a method or api to watch on address A to get automated notifications? What is the best practice for these payin notifications of many (~100+) addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to `Transfer` event logs emitted by the USDT contract. As defined in the [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard, the second param of the event log is the recipient address.

Example using [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-logs):

```
const options = {
    address: "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7", // USDT contract on Ethereum
    topics: [
        web3.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)"), // hash of the event definition
        null, // any sender
        ["0xFFfFfFffFFfffFFfFFfFFFFFffFFFffffFfFFFfF"] // recipient addresses
    ]
};

web3.eth.subscribe("logs", options, (err, data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Petr! I guess I have to keep the subscription running, right? Is using The GRAPH's subgraph a better solution?

Comment: @Ning That's correct about the subscription running... My knowledge of subgraph is limited, but I haven't found any webhooks in their documentation. But if there's a way for the subgraph to proactively notify you, then you could also use that solution. Otherwise you'd need to poll their API which is not ideal.